# WinForms RichTextBox - InvalidOperationException: Cannot load the text - happens only in .Net 6

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0

I'm using System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox, and have the following code:

```
    var testRichTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
    var testText = @"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Courier New;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;}\fs20{\cf0 \ud{\u160}}\line }";
    testRichTextBox.Rtf = testText;
```

This **same** code works perfectly in **.Net 4.7.2**.

When trying to run it in **.Net 6**, the following exception is produced:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot load the text.
   at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.StreamIn(Stream data, SF flags)
   at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.StreamIn(String str, SF flags)
   at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.set_Rtf(String value)
```

Couldn't find any documentation about it in the WinForms breaking changes in .Net 6 on MSDN, what can be the cause for that?

EDIT:

The code is executed on the same machine, changing .Net versions via Visual Studio

```
#if !NETCOREAPP
            var testRichTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            var testText = @"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Courier New;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;}\fs20{\cf0 \ud{\u160}}\line }";
            testRichTextBox.Rtf = testText;
#endif
#if NETCOREAPP
            var testRichTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            var testText = @"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Courier New;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;}\fs20{\cf0 \ud{\u160}}\line }";
            testRichTextBox.Rtf = testText;
#endif
```

Comment: Are you running the working and non working on the same machine?  The font may not be installed on the Net 6 machine.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, on the exact same machine.
Changing .Net version via Visual Studio.
You can try the code I've added in the Edit section in my question

Comment: Just tried that code in LINQPad 7; I get the error for .NET 6 and .NET 5, but not for .NET Core 3.1, so it looks like a potential regression.

Comment: Assume you are using same VS and just changing the target.  Are you doing clean build after changing target version?  Are you installing on different machine?  May need to install a different runtime version on target machine.

Comment: @jdweng I am using the same VS and just changing the target.
I have a clean build after changing the target version.
I'm not yet installing anything, just running the code locally on my machine

Comment: Remove `\ud{\u160}`

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that previous .Net version prior to 5 and 6 seem to be more lax about enforcing strict RTF.

I had a formatting issue with my RTF string where I was missing a closing } and it worked in .Net 4.7.2 but would error in the same way you described in .Net 6.  Took me doing some research in the RTF standard to figure it out.

Probably worth validating the RTF, although for me that proved harder than I expected as tools to do that seem to be lacking.